# Bubble sort is not sorting - IntDoublePair

Tags: sorting, hadoop

I have implemented bubble sort in order to sort the IntDoublePair. For instance:

```
[1 0.5]
[1 0.8]
[1 0.67]
```

sorted as:

```
[1 0.5]
[1 0.67]
[1 0.8]
```

When I executed the code, it gave me the data not in sorted order. I am confused that where am I going wrong. I need some assistance.

```
private ArrayList<IntDoubleTextPair> sortCollection(ArrayList<IntDoubleTextPair> collection)
    {
        for (int current = 0; current < collection.size(); current++)
        {
            for (int next = 1; next < collection.size(); next++)
            {
                if (collection.get(current).getFirst().get() >= collection.get(next).getFirst().get())
                {
                    if (collection.get(current).getSecond().get() > collection.get(next).getSecond().get())
                    {
                        temp = collection.get(next);

                        collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
                        collection.set(current, temp);
                    }
                }
}
}
return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have some faulty logic:

```
  if (collection.get(current).getFirst().get() >= collection.get(next).getFirst().get())
  {
      if (collection.get(current).getSecond().get() > collection.get(next).getSecond().get())
      {
          temp = collection.get(next);
          collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
          collection.set(current, temp);
      }
  }
```

with those two nested if statements, the switch won't happen in this example, but it needs to:

```
[2 .1]
[1 .9]
```

because even though the first if statement evaluates true, the second if statement fails because it only looks at the second number. Perhaps this would work better:

```
  if (collection.get(current).getFirst().get() >= collection.get(next).getFirst().get())
  {
      if (collection.get(current).getFirst().get() == collection.get(next).getFirst().get())
      {
          if (collection.get(current).getSecond().get() > collection.get(next).getSecond().get())
          {
          temp = collection.get(next);

          collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
          collection.set(current, temp);
          }
      }

      else
      {
          temp = collection.get(next);

          collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
          collection.set(current, temp);
      }
  }
```

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Still not sorting properly. Is the outer and inner loop initialization correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sort should work at least for the array that you are passing (although there is a problem in nested if conditions), but there might be an issue when you pass reference to temp in swap operation so try creating a temp object and instead of passing reference pass the values :

```
private ArrayList<IntDoubleTextPair> sortCollection(ArrayList<IntDoubleTextPair> collection)
    {
        for (int current = 0; current < collection.size(); current++)
        {
            for (int next = 1; next < collection.size(); next++)
            {
                if (collection.get(current).getFirst().get() >= collection.get(next).getFirst().get())
                {

                    if (collection.get(current).getSecond().get() > collection.get(next).getSecond().get())
                    {
                        IntDoubleTextPair temp=  new IntDoubleTextPair();
                        temp.getFirst() = collection.get(next).getFirst();
                        temp.getSecond() = collection.get(next).getSecond();

                        collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
                        collection.set(current, temp);
                    }
                    else if(collection.get(current).getFirst().get() != collection.get(next).getFirst().get()){
                        IntDoubleTextPair temp=  new IntDoubleTextPair();
                        temp.getFirst() = collection.get(next).getFirst();
                        temp.getSecond() = collection.get(next).getSecond();

                        collection.set(next, collection.get(current));
                        collection.set(current, temp);

                        }
                }
}
}
return collection;
}
```

Comment: I have reinitialized the temp object as you said, but no luck

Comment: Then I think, there should be a problem with collection.set() method, did you debug and see that it is working properly ? You might need to override the method. Or you can just change the first and second values  of current and next object the same way you created temp:

Comment: It should probably be okay to swap using shallow copies, yeah? I don't think it's completely necessary to create a new IntDoubleTextPair for temp. I may be mistaken though.